# quality loss of CALayers in AVVideoComposition?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation, avfoundation

I'm using the AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool to add CALayers to a captured video. The images used for the layers are fairly high-res PNGs that have so far scaled down pretty well for other uses, but when I put them in the composition they lose a whole bunch of their quality, no matter what the original size of the layer was, and appear very pixelated. The video is recorded with the AVSessionPreset640x480, and the video for the composition comes out in 480x360 (which seems like kind of an odd resolution), so I'm gonna try to have my artist resize the layers so that they're in the proper size for a 480x360 video, but I'm not super confident that it'll help. Anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

When you export your animated video then set the AVAssetExportSession's presetName to AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality.

E.g:

let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)